# Python 2.7 portScanner

Tags: python-2.7, sockets

I am wondering why my portScanner module runs and claims that all my ports are closed?

I am running Python 2.7 because thats what Violent Python(the book) uses.

Only solution I have tried so far was I have set my DNS to 8.8.8.8 and secondary to 8.8.4.4 because my socket takes 'www.google.com' as the Ip.

Code:

```
import socket

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
serverIp = socket.gethostbyname('www.google.com')

def pscan(port):
    try:
        s.connect((serverIp,port))
        return True
    except:
        return False

for x in range(1,101):  
    if pscan(x):
        print("Port %d is open!!!" % (x))
    else:
        print("Port %d is closed" % (x))
```

Answer (score 1):

You only create a single socket and try to use it in multiple connect's. This is not possible. If you look at the details of the Exception you will notice that the first one (port 1) fails slowly because the connect timed out but the following ones all fail quickly because of *"Operation already in progress"*.

The fix is to create a new socket before each `connect`. Additionally it might be helpful to reduce the time it tries to connect with `s.settimeout(1)`.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thank you.